# Datatable not update just this row but all table

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I am pull php data and including inside my table, more specific, inside of the tag tbody, all work well until realize that when I update a line of the table through fnUpdate this don't update just one line but update all table datatable. The question is: how I make it update just this line?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      var table = $('#tabela_produto2');
      var tabela = table.dataTable({    

        "pageLength": 1,
        "lengthMenu": [[7, 25, 50, 100, -1], [7, 25, 50, 100, "Todas"]],

         "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-9] },
            { "width": "7%", "targets": 0 }
          ],
            "oLanguage": {

      "sLengthMenu":    "Produtos de Locação por Página: _MENU_",
      "sInfo":          "_TOTAL_ Produtos de Locação",
      "sInfoFiltered":  "(Total: _MAX_ Produtos de Locação)"
    },
    "sDom": '<"top"fi>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
              "order": [
        [0, "asc"]
      ], // set first column as a default sort by asc,

      "bPaginate": true
           });

      table.on('click', '.atualiza', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0]; // here the row to update
      tabela.fnUpdate('test33' , nRow,4,false); // here do update (but it
                          update all table and not just this line                                                
      tabela.fnDraw();
    });
        //tabela.fnUpdate('test' , 0,0,false ); // Row
        //tabela.fnDeleteRow( 0 );['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','d','4','4','9']
       //tabela.fnDraw();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I include the php file with all rows <row> and <td> of this way:
        <tbody>
        <?php include_once "tabelas/tabela_produto2.php";?>
        </tbody>